# Apache Camel framework is converting the value 99999999999.99 into 9.999999999999E10

Tags: apache-camel, data-conversion, bigdecimal, exponential

I have a json payload where one value for a key is 99999999999.99. When I pass this value, the camel is converting this into 9.999999999999E10. The camel version I'm using is 2.22.1.

I've upgraded the camel version to 2.23.2 but didn't work. I can upgrade to another version if needed.

I expect the value to be 99999999999.99. I need no conversion happening in the framework.

Comment: Those are the same values, so it's not a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

As @james-k-polk already commented, this is **not a conversion** but a **different way to show the same number** in Java.

The extension `E10` means that the decimal point has to be shifted by 10 (`e` is for exponent, see also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation)).

So that means: `9.999999999999E10` is equal to `99999999999.99`. It is just another way to display the same value.

If this different display form is causing a specific problem, create a new question for it.